# What difference does defining 'position: relative' make over, when position property is not used at all in CSS?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

`Position: Relative` fixes the margins relative to parent element in html. Isn't this what happens anyway, when we define margins (or paddings) in CSS?

What is the difference and uses of defining it as such?

I see in defining dropdown menues, the parent of dropdown element is defined with `position: relative` and its supposed to have an impact on the child element which is defined as `position: absolute.`

This is given at : https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_text

But it doesn't make any impact when i delete the `position: relative` of parent, same results are showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining `position: relative;` on the parent comes into play when the children elements are given `top`, `right`, `bottom`, or `left` properties (with `position: absolute`). This is because the position of the child element is in respect to the first parent element which has a `position` other than `position: static` (the default value for `position`).

In other words, by removing `position: relative` from the parent element the `.dropdown-content` is now positioned in respect to the body element (or whatever parent element contains a position of `relative`, `static`, or `fixed`. If you were to give the `.dropdown-content` element a `top: 10px;`, this would be 10px from the top of the `body` element.

By giving the `.dropdown` a `position: relative` the `.dropdown-content` will be positioned in respect to the `.dropdown`, so it would be 10px from the top of `.dropdown` - meaining `dropdown-content` will appear at the top of the page.

### Without `position: relative` on parent

```css
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### With `position: relative` on parent

```css
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below to open the dropdown content.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <span>Mouse over me</span>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```